# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol - when creating abstract class c++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, abstract, lnk2001

UrzadzenieElektroniczne is my abstract Class and class Komputer inherits from it. I still get errors. I tried to fix them but none of the resolutions I found on the internet worked. Is there a problem with the definition and declaration of my virtual function or should I look for an error somewhere else?:
Errors:

```
     1>CKomputer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void__thiscall Komputer::wlaczenieurz(void)" (?wlaczenieurz@Komputer@@UAEXXZ)
```

## UrzadzenieElektroniczne.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class UrzadzenieElektroniczne
{
public:
int czy_wlaczony;
UrzadzenieElektroniczne();
~UrzadzenieElektroniczne();
virtual void wlaczenieurz() = 0;
private:

protected:
string producent;
};
```

## CKomputer.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "UrzadzenieElektroniczne.h"
#include "Procesor.h"
#include "KartaDzwiekowa.h"


using namespace std;

class Komputer: public UrzadzenieElektroniczne
{
private:
Procesor procesor;
KartaDzwiekowa *karta_dzwiekowa;

string nazwa_komputera;
int ram;
int ile_kart_dzwiekowych;
public:

void wlaczenieurz();
```

## CKomputer.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>


#include "CKomputer.h"
#include "Procesor.h"
#include "KartaDzwiekowa.h"

void UrzadzenieElektroniczne::wlaczenieurz()
{
if (czy_wlaczony == 0)
    cout<<"Komputer wylaczony"<<endl;
if (czy_wlaczony == 1)
    cout<<"Komputer wlaczony"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should probably be qualified as a member of `Komputer`:

```
void Komputer::wlaczenieurz()
//   ^^^^^^^^
{
if (czy_wlaczony == 0)
    cout<<"Komputer wylaczony"<<endl;
if (czy_wlaczony == 1)
    cout<<"Komputer wlaczony"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: But I want `wlaczenieurz()` to be a virtual function of a `class UrzadzenieElektroniczne`.

Comment: You have declared it as a pure virtual function in `UrzadzenieElektroniczne`. That means it must be implemented by derived classes. Since `Komputer` is a derived class, it must implement this function.

Comment: Ok. That was my mistake. I thought that abstract class must implement the virtual function. Now it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's a typo.  :)

```
void UrzadzenieElektroniczne::wlaczenieurz()
```

should be:

```
void Komputer::wlaczenieurz()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `void UrzadzenieElektroniczne::wlaczenieurz()` instead of `void Komputer::wlaczenieurz()`. The tricky part is that C++ actually allows to have definitions of pure virtal functions. Thru they can be accessed by non virtual calls only.
Your code declares 2 `wlaczenieurz()` one in base class, and it is pure virtual, thus it doesn't require to be defined, and one in derived class that *must* have definition.
While in your case it is clearly misprint, in general you may have some default implementation of pure virtual function, that can be used in derived class by adding `using` statement.
For example in your case `using UrzadzenieElektroniczne::wlaczenieurz;` in `Komputer` instead of `wlaczenieurz` declaration should fix error as well.

Comment: But i define `void UrzadzenieElektroniczne::wlaczenieurz()` as you can see in my code and it does not work. When I defined `Komputer::wlaczenieurz()` it works, but I dont understand if it is still a virtual function of `class UrzadzenieElektroniczne`

Comment: Yes it is still virtual function of `UrzadzenieElektroniczne` implemented by `Komputer`. You don't need(thru allowed to) define `UrzadzenieElektroniczne::wlaczenieurz()` it is responsibility of derived class to implement pure virtual functions;